# ipython to run a file before open in each session

Tags: python, session, configuration, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to have ipython to run a config file where
I have my global variable written in there ? So we have multiple servers with different user name and password and frequent module that I am using. Is there a way to put that in a filer prior to open python session ? I'm in windows and new to ipython.

```
from pandas import * 
import numpy as np
import pyodbc 

cursor = connect() 

user1 = foo
pwd1 = xx1

user2 = foo2
```

So each time that I open a session in ipython it would already have this code run.

Comment: Have you read [Configuration and customization](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/index.html)? If you just skim the Overview section, that should answer everything you need to know. If it doesn't, you should at least have a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a macro called something like `server_setup`:

```
In [1]: from pandas import * 
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: 
   ...: user1 = 'foo'
   ...: pwd1 = 'xx1'
   ...: 
   ...: user2 = 'foo2'

In [2]: %macro server_setup 1
Macro `server_setup` created. To execute, type its name (without quotes).
```

Store it:

```
%store server_setup
Stored 'server_setup' (Macro)
```

Then set

```
c.StoreMagics.autorestore = True
```

in your IPython profile. Every time you open a new IPython session, just type `server_setup` and it'll run the setup code.